# Validation of submitEntities Method does not run when mocked at unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, moq

I'm working on a legacy project which is created with .NET Framework 4.8, locator pattern, and business factory to instantiate businesses.

I'm trying to add unit tests using MSTest and MOQ.
The `SubmitEntities` method in mocked business does not run validations. I mean when I run a test that is expected to throw an exception, it passes successfully. I have no idea why is this happening.

Also, I don't have experience in writing unit tests and this is my first time.

**In short**, I'm expecting to get exception when the test is run, but it finishes with `submittedBalanceMappings` with a count of more than zero.

The test class constructor is:

```
private readonly BalanceMappingBusinessService _balanceMappingBusinessService;
private readonly Mock<IBalanceMappingBusiness> _mockBalanceMappingBusiness = new Mock<IBalanceMappingBusiness>();
    
public BalanceMapping()
{
     _balanceMappingBusinessService = new BalanceMappingBusinessService(_mockBalanceMappingBusiness.Object);
}
```

The test is:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SubmitEntities_NoDataWillBeSubmitted_IfColumnSettingIdDoesNotExist()
{
    // Arrange
    await LoginWithSuperAdminAccount();

    var submittingBalanceMappings = new List<BalanceMappingEntity>
    {
        new BalanceMappingEntity
        {
            AdjustedBalanceDetailId = adjutedBalanceDetailId,
            ColumnSettingId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            EntityState = EntityState.Added
        }
    };

    var submittedBalanceMappings = new List<BalanceMappingEntity>();

    _mockBalanceMappingBusiness.Setup(
        bmb => bmb.SubmitEntities(submittingBalanceMappings))
        .Callback((List<BalanceMappingEntity> balanceMappings) => submittedBalanceMappings.AddRange(balanceMappings));


    var adjutedBalanceDetailId = GetAdjustedBalanceDetail();

    //Act
    _balanceMappingBusinessService.SubmitEntities(submittingBalanceMappings );

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(submittedBalanceMappings.Count == 0);
}
```

The SubmitEntities method is:

```
public void SubmitEntities(List<BalanceMappingEntity> balanceMappings)
{
    try
    {
        ValidateSubmittingBalanceMappings(balanceMappings);

        using var onlineUnitOfWork = new OnlineUnitOfWork();

        foreach (var balanceMapping in balanceMappings)
        {
            balanceMapping.AccountId = ReusableObjects.Current.CurrentAuthenticatedAccountId;

            onlineUnitOfWork.Submit(balanceMapping);
        }

        onlineUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debuged to check if the call goes enters SubmitEntities? Could you show SubmitEntities method?

Comment: I did debug the method, NO it does not go through the SubmitEntities.
NP I'll do it.

Comment: Guys, I need help.

Comment: I don't know where you are at. 
First, I would debug the test method from the 1st line and check where it doesnt behave as expected. 
Second you could also, IF EASY, not mock IBalanceMappingBusiness and create a public class MyMock : IBalanceMappingsBusiness with empty implementations.

Sometimes mocks just "swallow" method calls